# how does keyboard input reach the right virtual terminal in GUI

Tags: operating-system, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Lets say we have an 8 core system running linux and you are using GUI desktop and have 10-20 terminal open.

When you type something, the user input appears on the correct terminal. How does that happen.  For example the keyboard interrupt can arrive on any of the cpu, how is it routed to the correct process is my question (given that at a time 10 processes are waiting for user input)

## This is what I know:

1. Keyboard driver will have an interrupt handler that reads the input and copies it to a buffer which might be processed by some high priority work-queue. (not necessary but that is what I feel will happen)
2. ---
3. This buffer has to be copied into buffer of the file descriptor for stdin of the currently active shell.

## What I don't know

How does the work-queue work function determine which process is running the currently active shell.

Answer (score 0):

It just does know. One of all of the process is marked as the current for console I/O. You switch to another, that other gets marked as the current. I don't know the details of the implementation, but that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The work queue function does not determine which process is running - this is done at a much higher level. The keyboard device is exported by the kernel through a device file in `/dev/input/` (on my system it is `/dev/input/event3` - you can look at `/dev/input/by-id` to see which one corresponds to your keyboard). This device file is opened by the X server in order to receive the events (look for the device file in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to see where this happens). The X server thus receives all the keyboard events and dispatches them to the right client itself. Knowing which window has the focus, it can put the corresponding input event into the client queue queue and send a signal to the corresponding process, which is waken up and can process the event.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev and related links for more information.